# How to protect valuables at gym

Tags: gym

Yesterday, during the 1 hour I was at the gym, someone forced the lock and got into my locker.  When I was done showering I came back to my locker and opened my combination lock as normal, and opened the locker to discover that everything was messed up and rearranged, with my wallet out and on top of my pants.  Luckily, nothing was missing.  (Not even my phone!)  I took a closer look at the Master combination lock and saw that there was significant damages to the outside of it.  Interestingly, whatever tool the thief used to force open the lock, left the lock in a usable state.  They were able to lock it again when they were done rifling through my stuff, and I was able to open the lock with the combination.

So my question for this community is:  what is the best type of lock to use on the lockers in a typical gym?  Clearly the Master combination lock is vulnerable (although the version I had was slightly smaller than a full sized combo lock).  Do the people here use anything in particular to guard against tool-equipped gym thieves?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is about safekeeping. You should be taking this up with the gym.

Comment: I did take it up with the gym.  I wanted to get the advice of other members of this community who are into Physical Fitness.

Comment: How about if we leave it for one day.  If no one comments or answers I will close the questions and delete it.

Comment: You don't need to close the question. If not enough people agree with me, the question will remain open. I don't have all the power :) But I think you might get some cool ideas if you post it at the Lifehacks StackExchange instead. http://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Simple solution is carry your gym bag around with you while you workout.

Comment: leave all valuables in the car and carry the car key with you along your training :-)

Comment: @son15 thanks for the comment.  I do not want to carry my gym bag around with me in the gym.  Partly because if everyone did that it would make a very cluttered gym floor, but also because have to track something with valuables in it while working out would serve as a distraction.

Comment: @bantandor thanks for the idea!  I have considered this route but I am concerned that my car would be broken into.  While researching this issue the general consensus seems to be that cars in gym parking lots get broken into more often that gym lockers.  I might try locking them in the glove box, but that seems easily broken into as well!

Comment: You may consider moving to another GYM that is safer :-). I hope you find a good solution for you soon. Take care

Answer (score 1):

Place your phone and wallet in a small bag and have it with you inside them gym.I doubt anyone would steal your clothes.

Comment: I am not sure this is the answer for me.  I really don't want to have to carry my phone and wallet around with me in the gym it seems very inconvenient.  I am leaning towards the car idea.  Thanks for the answer though!

Comment: Still I recommend you place your valuables not on sight  if you place them inyour car because you never know when someone will break a window just to steal a wallet.